# Continuous map from compact space into Hausdorff is surjective

Tags: general-topology

Let

$$f: X \rightarrow Y$$

be continuous map of topological spaces with $X$ compact, $Y$ Hausdorff, and connected. If $f$ is an open map, show $f$ is onto.

For this do I just need to show

$$f(X) = Y$$

where its clear that $f(X) \subset Y$ and in order to show $f(X)$ is all of $Y$, since $Y$ is connected its enough to prove $f(X)$ is both open and closed $Y$ and is thus all of $Y$, but we get closed since $f(X)$ is a compact subset of a Hausdorff space (something I can prove) thus it just remains for me to show $f(X) \subset Y$ is open?

Comment: By definition, an open map sends an open set to an open set. Is $X$ open in $X$?

Comment: of course @ArturoMagidin

Comment: This is not necessarily true; consider $X = \emptyset$. But if we assume $X \neq \emptyset$, this is true since $f(X)$ is both open and closed.

Comment: The image $f[X]$ is a compact subset of $Y$ because $X$ is compact and $f$ is continuous. So $f[X]$ is closed in $Y$ because $Y$ is Hausdorff. And $f[X]$ is open in $Y$ because $f$ is an open map and $X$ is open in $X$. So $f[X]$ is open-and-closed in $Y.$ So $f[X]=\emptyset$ or $f[X]=Y$ because $Y $ is connected.